# Error on opening a solution in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

The problem here is whenever I try to open a .sln in Visual Studio 2013, it throws the following error:

> The data provided was not valid xml. See log for more details.

I see no xml in my solution since mine is a complete VC++ project.

So, the question is what is the xml mentioned in the error and what log should I look into. I didn't any log in the solution directory or the temp folder.

edit: Snap attached

[image]

Comment: Well the solution and project files themselves are xml.  Do you have a more complete error messages, is there anything more in the log file.

Comment: @tolanj that's all what I can infer from the error

Comment: open visual studio via devenv.exe /log, reproduce the issue, go to %APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<version>\ActivityLog.xml and get the end of the activity log which look like its associated with the error, post it.

Comment: @tolanj I tried doing the same, you mentioned but found no clue in it. I suspect this could be a problem since I've updated Visual Studio 2013 with update 5.